# This use of "that" in British English

Tags: grammar, british-english

Probably informal if not exclusively colloquial. The pattern is as follows

> <adjective>, that

Some that I've seen:

> Awful, that.

> Wonderful, that.

> Suspicious, that.

I understand the meaning and the nuance it has, but I'm wondering if there's any documentation on this use? What part of speech would it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition 2 at [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/that) describes this usage of the pronoun '*that*' as "
**referring to a specific thing previously mentioned, known, or understood.**" I haven't been able to find anything about its use.

Ngram and Google aren't much help in situations like this, where the punctuation is crucial and where it's impossible to exclude e.g."(It's) **wonderful that** (something happened)".

All I found were one or two examples of its use in the 1840's. For example by James Fennimore Cooper, in [Roberts' Semi-monthly Magazine,1841](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Roberts_Semi_monthly_Magazine/kuQRAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22odd%20that%22,%20said&pg=PA71&printsec=frontcover) (P.71):

> "Anna is not a favorite with her sister."
>  "Very odd, that," said
> the aunt gravely.

I wonder if, rather than it being a re-arrangement of "That's [adjective]," the pattern might be an abbreviation of "How [adjective] that is."

> “How funny that is, Wendale," the young man rejoined. [*The Shamrock*,
> 1868]